# Light HTTP Stack for Visual C++ Project

Tags: windows, visual-studio, http, visual-c++

I just want a light HTTP stack. Something similar to `WinInet` or `WinHTTP`, with cookie support, etc. Are there any good alternatives to those? Seems like I find a bug or limitation in either one that I end up hung up on.

Comment: What is your actual problem with either of the libraries?

Comment: WinHTTP has functions that aren't reentrant, WinInet is outdated.

Comment: What is your target platform (Win-desktop, WinCE...) ?